# If a,b are integers such that a congruent b mod p for every positive prime p, prove that a=b

Tags: number-theory

I need some help with this problem
If a,b are integers such that a congruent b mod p for every positive prime p, prove that a=b.

Comment: Hint: $a$ and $b$ are congruent mod some prime $p$ with $p > a$ and $p > b$.

Comment: Alternatively: suppose $a\neq b$. Then $|a-b|$ must be at least $p$ for every prime $p$. But there is no common upper bound of all primes.

Comment: Alternatively-alternatively: $$a=b\pmod p\;\;\forall\,p\iff p\mid (a-b)\;\forall\,p$$ Now, what integers you know that are divisible by **all** primes?

Comment: So, this will be a new proof that there are infinitely many primes!  Finitely many $p$ can partition $\mathbb Z$ into only finitely many congruence classes, but we know $\mathbb Z$ is infinite, so some class would have more than one element...  (Now all we need to do is prove this problem without using the fact that there are infinitely many primes.)

Answer (score 2):

We pick a prime $p$ greater than $2\max(|a|,|b|)$.

We know the following:

- $a-b \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

  This is because $a \equiv b \pmod p$ or equivalently $p$ divides $a-b$.  Thus $a-b \in \{\ldots,-2p,-p,0,p,2p,\ldots\}$.
- $-\lfloor p/2 \rfloor < a < \lfloor p/2 \rfloor$ and $-\lfloor p/2 \rfloor < b < \lfloor p/2 \rfloor$.

  This is because we chose $p>2\max(|a|,|b|)$.

The second dot point can be used to eliminate the possibility that $a-b=kp$ for $k \geq 1$ and $k \leq -1$.

Comment: +1 Nice that you took care of the possibility of positive and negative integers.